# Magento get a list of products that are not related to any category

Tags: php, collections, magento

I was able to make an ordered list of categories with child products, now i need to add a list of products that are not related to any category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('category_ids','');
```

Comment: hi jonathan, thanks for always being around to answer my questions, let me give a try, i'll let you know

Comment: well, i was looking into eav_attribute table and category_ids exist, so, why a get an exception a:5:{i:0;s:79:"SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE (e.category_ids = '')

Comment: your response didn't work, but served me as guide, this work for me,                                                                   public function getProdNoRelated()
    {
        $c = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like'=>'%'.$this->getRequest()->getParam('q').'%'));;
        $temp;
        foreach($c as $_c){
            $_c->load();
            $cat = $_c->load()->getCategory_ids();
            if(!count($cat))
                $temp[]=$_c;
        }
        return $temp;
    }

Comment: I'd like to think there is a more efficient soution, having to load each product is likely to perform badly.  I'll see what I can find.

Comment: you're right, meanwhile i'll use this way...let meknow if you find another solution