# Magento list products that arent in a category

Tags: php, magento

I need to list all products that are inside a category. In Magento, you don't need to specify a category for a product, so i want to list all those products that don't belong to a category.

This is what i tried but it gives me an error:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($productCollection as $_product){

    $productId = $_product->getId();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); 

    $currentCatIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    $categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('url')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $currentCatIds)
                 ->addIsActiveFilter();
    $i = 0;

    foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){
      $i++;
      //echo $cat->getName().' '.$cat->getUrl();
    }   

    if($i) echo $product->getName(); 
}
```

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567729/magento-find-orphan-products or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717664/magento-get-a-list-of-products-that-are-not-related-to-any-category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_ids','');
```

See [Magento get a list of products that are not related to any category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717664/magento-get-a-list-of-products-that-are-not-related-to-any-category)

Comment: Newest magento as in v1.7-1.8?